# How is this axiom useful?

Tags: probability

Today I had my first lecture of probability. The lecturer gave some rigorous definitions, and there is one part I don't understand.

Let $\Omega$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of subsets of $\Omega$. We call $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra if:

1) $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$

2) If $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$

3) For every countable sequence $(A_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ in $\mathcal{F}$, also have $\cup_{n \geqslant 1} A_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$.

I think I can see why we'd like to have the first two axioms and how they are useful for creating the notion of an "event space", but why is the third axiom there?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Σ-algebra#Motivation might provide some insight: *“Many uses of measure [...] involve limits of sequences of sets. For this, closure under countable unions and intersections is paramount.”*

Comment: She talked about elements of $\mathcal F$ being "events", so it is useful to be able to talk about the event of any of a number of other events happening. This is the union over a countable sequence of those events. It means that we can be sure things like $\mathbb P(A \cup B)$ are defined, basically.

Comment: It might help to learn the story about how mathematicians attempted to define the "measure" of an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R^n$, but then discovered that if we assign a measure to all subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (even very strange and pathological subsets) then it's impossible for the basic properties we desire of a measure to be satisfied. So, we give up and define the measure only of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ that are sufficiently nice, in some sense. But now we need to know that a union of "measurable" subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ is guaranteed to be measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one example, we'd like to be able to define the notion of a random variable that can take countably many values. Let $\Omega = \{1,2,\ldots\}$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal P(\Omega)$ (the power set of $\Omega$), and define $\mathbb P(\{n\}) = (1-p)^{n-1}p$ for some $0<p<1$. For distinct positive integers $n,m$, the sets $\{n\}$ and $\{m\}$ are disjoint, so by the countable additivity axiom,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(\{n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1}p = 1.
$$
Since $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\} = \Omega$, it follows that $\mathbb P(\Omega)=1$ and this defines a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$. We can define a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by $X(\omega) = \omega$ with distribution function
$$
F_X(x) = \mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\leqslant x\}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} (1-p)^{n-1}p = 1 - (1-p)^{\lfloor x\rfloor},\ x\geqslant 0.
$$

This would not be possible if we only had finite additivity, i.e. if $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in\mathcal F$ are disjoint then $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(A)$.